# How to make looping background in Expression Blend / wpf?

Tags: wpf, animation, silverlight, expression-blend

How can i make something similar to this looping animation? http://www.jimmcneill.com/loopdemo2.html

Comment: you pretty much have follow steps in the tutorial you referenced

Answer (score 0):

I would use an [ImageBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush.aspx) with `TileMode` set to `Tile`, perhaps on a [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx). Use a [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx) to scroll through.